# How to disable the compiz fps cap?

Tags: unity, compiz, framerate

I have my monitor running at 165 Hz on Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity and while the mouse pointer is updated at this frequency, as soon as a grab a window and move it around, the movement becomes choppy. The plugin Compiz Benchmark corroborates this by showing a maximum framerate of 60 fps (it shows much less when there is no change but since G-Sync doesn't seem to be used, I'm not sure what the practical benefits of this are).

With a GTX 1070 and an i7-6700K, there shouldn't be any hardware limitations behind this maximum framerate and on Windows 10, dragging windows is perfectly smooth until I hit my second, 60 Hz screen (which I deactivated on Linux for the sake of testing if it the root of compiz's 60 Hz cap. It is not.)

So does compiz have an fps cap and if so, why and how do I deactivate it?

**Edit:** The "Refresh Rate" setting under "Composite" doesn't have any influence on the rate at which windows are drawn. I am, however, now sure it's compiz's fault because I tried metacity for comparison and dragging windows instantly became smooth. Also, my Unity dock disappeared, so it wasn't really a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Composite->Refresh Rate *is* actually the right setting. However, having a second monitor makes all of compiz always run at the lowest refresh rate supported, regardless of the setting. Anyway, for future reference, these two lines work for me, as long as I only have the 165Hz monitor connected:

```
xrandr --verbose --output DP-2 --mode 2560x1440 --rate 165
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/composite/refresh-rate "165"
```